# Recover/reinstall UEFI partition after dd to /null

Tags: linux, partitioning, uefi, partition-recovery, fstab

Has you can guess from the tittle I'm a moron. I got angry against an USB key and try to format it's partitions with a `dd` and /null , but instead I deleted my `sda1` and `sda2` partitions.

I realized rapidly my mistake and didn't shutdown my computer, so my OS is still running.

I have now only my `sda3`

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jun  6 19:40 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 Jun  6 19:40 /dev/sda3
```

if I `cat` my `fstab` I get

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f16adf40-841d-48de-afb6-bdbe66bd6eae /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2008-2EBF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I must say I'm a bit lost and didn't quiet yet understood how the UEFI, GRUB is working, and how `fstab` works.

If I do `ll /boot` it's not empty:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249214 Dec 11 15:36 abi-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1243479 Dec  2  2016 abi-4.4.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190517 Dec 11 15:36 config-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   189877 Dec  2  2016 config-4.4.0-53-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     1024 Jun 23  2017 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Apr 17 23:05 grub/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 48667470 Apr 18 07:27 initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 48377536 Jan  6 14:59 initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Jun 23  2017 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3887726 Dec 11 15:36 System.map-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3874377 Dec  2  2016 System.map-4.4.0-53-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7104112 Dec 11 15:36 vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7065648 Dec 13  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
```

but `ll /boot/efi` is empty.

Do I need to remount or recreate the 2 partitions `sda1` and `sda2`? Can I download an EFI? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

People are divided on two categories. Ones are making backups. Others already making backups. I believe that you have backup.

You need to re-create Partition table via interactive `fdisk`
If you have still your OS is running, you may get partition boundaries from kernel memory.

Here is an example from my working system (RHEL7 with UEFI):

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda 

Disk /dev/sda: 300.0 GB, 299966445568 bytes, 585871964 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a146c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          526336     1050623      262144    6  FAT16
/dev/sda3         1050624   585871359   292410368   8e  Linux LVM
```

You have loose /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 info, below the way to restore.
Find the files with boundary information:

```
# find /sys -name start
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda1/start
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda2/start
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda3/start
....
```

Start block of `sda1` partition from kernel memory

```
# cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda1/start
2048
```

End block of `sda1` partition from kernel memory

```
echo end $((
$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda1/size) \
+ \
$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda1/start) \
- 1 \
))
end 526335
```

Start block of `sda2` partition from kernel memory

```
# cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda2/start
526336
```

End block of `sda2` partition from kernel memory

```
echo end $((\
$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda2/size)\
+ \
$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:1:0/0:1:0:0/block/sda/sda2/start)\
- 1 \
))
end 1050623
```

Now you need to re-create lost partitions with this boundaries with interactive `fdisk`. Do not forget to set partition type.

After you restore partitions, you need to check their filesystems.
You are writing, that /boot/efi is empty, but it should be empty in the only case if you are NOT using UEFI.
You could try to restore it with reinstalling `grub2-efi-x64` package.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi) topic to continue restoration.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error. I firstly save everything that was important to me and created an USB bootable just in case. Then I used testDisk, and since my partitions was not overwritten, I had no issues recovering my partition table and my data with a quick search (UEFI sda1, and swupdate sda2). I finally checked that it had worked with gparted and rebooted my system.

For your information don't do a deep-search with testDisk from on your disk and from you disk, it bug and tell you it doesn't have enough space.

Thankfully everything is ok. thank for the help guys.