# Advice with installing grub bootloader to another disk from a working Linux OS

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I am trying to install grub from my functioning Debian-12 system to another disk in my PC.

**Problem**: I have two disks, *disk1* and *disk2*. *Disk1* with working Debian 12 (As mentioned.) and the other *Disk2*, on this one there is a Windows 10 and cloned partition of my Debian from *Disk1*.

As can be seen below, my attempt at installing grub was semi-successful. But I am having troubles with configuration of grub, to recognize the two partition on *disk2*, even if I boot from *disk2* grub still boots from the partition on *disk1*

What I've done so far is that I've repartitioned *disk2* - deleted windows bootloader partition, shifted windows partition to the right, created EFI partition for the grub, via clonezila I've copied my Debian ext4 partition from *disk1* to *disk2*, created linux-swap partition.
Here is the output of **`lsblk`** command:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   237G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   977M  0 part [SWAP]
nvme1n1     259:4    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0   512M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0 232.8G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 660.9G  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p4 259:8    0  37.2G  0 part
```

Here is the partition scheme of *disk2* via **`fdisk -l /dev/disk2`**:

```
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ADATA LEGEND 800                        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BB47134C-B71E-4797-844A-799AF566DEF2

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2    1054720  489336831  488282112 232.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme1n1p3  489347072 1875390463 1386043392 660.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p4 1875400704 1953515519   78114816  37.2G Linux swap
```

Here is the **`tree /mnt/`** output of the EFI partition (Mounted to /mnt)

```
/mnt/
├── boot
│   ├── efi
│   │   └── grub
│   └── grub
└── EFI
    └── GRUB
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── fbx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi

7 directories, 6 files
```

So I guess that my grub install was semi-successful, but for some weird reason I am having troubles with configuring grub so that it recognizes the two above partitions.
I would add grub.cfg file but at this point I am kinda lost, since as you can see the `/boot/grub/` folder is kinda empty.

Please could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and help me with figuring this out?

Comment: The boot code in your PC will only read the bootloader from the first disk. That code can boot an OS on any disk. There is no reason to have another copy.

Comment: Whole point of doing this was to get rid of the first disk bc it being too small and also, it has one or more corrupted sectors, so that's why I've gotten a new one

Comment: This describes the steps. https://askubuntu.com/q/1267225

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is reinstall GRUB. There's a very good description of how to do that here -> [How to reinstall GRUB2 EFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi)
Or if you want an alternate try -> https://www.fosslinux.com/115040/a-complete-guide-to-installing-grub-bootloader-on-linux.htm
But most things about reinstalling or modifying your boot sequence are covered

Now very important! Create a Debian 12 Live image on a USB using your favorite image writer, Rufus or balenaEtcher are used a lot if you don't have one. Now boot it up and login to it user=user password=live. At this point you can either put a sudo in front of all your commands or do a sudo -i
Although you could use any live system at this level there may be somethings that are easier in Debian 12. You can open a teminal and providing you have a network you can install anything you don't have. Just remember to direct things to the the disk your trying to fix because your root is on the USB.
Now do a LSBLK to see all your devices, and get to work.